# Return null values for count operator after grouping

Tags: postgresql, count, isnull

I have select with 3 tables

```
SELECT pl."name" as "name", COALESCE(count(pb.*),0) as "pb_count"
FROM charging_station_places pl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN charging_stations st ON st."placeId" = pl."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN power_banks pb ON pb."chargingStationId" = st."id"
WHERE pb."status" = 'ready'
  AND pl."isHidden" IS NOT True 
GROUP BY pl."name"
ORDER BY "pb_count" ASC
```

The idea is to get 0 for rows (pl."name") where count(pb.*) is NULL. it is possible, that pb table will not have any records with pb."status" = 'ready'.

Searching through internet ideas, I tried COALESCE aproach, LEFT(OUTER), HAVING pb_count is NULL and other joins variants.
The sentence above is my last state which is still not working.
As result it shows records with pb_count equal 1 and above.

Comment: some test data, and possibly a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) might help.   Normally when `count(...)` returns 1, then the count IS equal to 1.

Comment: and you are right. the problem is that count doesn't return 0 if no records selected. I used filter in DB-GUL where set up "empty" for the pb_count for the select above and it returns required rows!
will try to add the data for a test

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in "where" conditions. It has to be included into joined table as condition and not be applied to overall select.

```
 SELECT pl."name" as "name", COALESCE(count(pb.*),0) as "pb_count"
    FROM charging_station_places pl 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN charging_stations st ON st."placeId" = pl."id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN power_banks pb ON pb."chargingStationId" = st."id" AND pb."status" = 'ready'
    WHERE pl."isHidden" IS NOT True 
    GROUP BY pl."name"
    ORDER BY "pb_count" ASC
```

Comment: Why: `WHERE pl."isHidden" IS NOT True` and not `WHERE pl."isHidden" IS False` ? You should not make expressions unnecessarily (more) difficult to read.

Comment: @Luuk - much appreciate!! :) Sure, you are right!